# Spring not finding AspectJ package

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm beggining my journey with Spring, trying to use `AspectJ` in `Spring` 3.2. Im following book *Spring in Action*. Author uses AspectJ by importing aspectJ packages this way:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
```

However using that leaves me with

```
package org.aspectj.lang.annotation does not exist
```

I tried importing `aspectj.jar` (version 1.8.4) to my libraries in `NetBeans`, without any effect. I have the jar just bellow dozen of `SPRING FRAMEWORK 3.2.3 RELEASE xxxxxx's`. It still does not find the package. What could cause this issue? Here's the beggining of my beans.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">

    <context:component-scan base-package="heyspring">

    </context:component-scan>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you move to Maven

Even if you want to work without Maven, read the following note carefully.

**Note**: even in [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/) you are able to download the **jars** required according with my dependencies shared below

Be totally sure you have the following in your `pom.xml` or *equivalent* **jars** files:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The following is **mandatory**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Of course you must set or configure each version, for Spring and AOP.

I have these three dependencies and work fine in my projects.

Comment: I have a Spring Boot Project, I was facing the same problem. Previously I had 'aspectjweaver' in the maven dependency. I added the 'aspectjrt' devpendency in my pom file and the said problem gone. Thanks @Manuel Jordan.

Answer (score 2):

For me reason was using using `<scope>` when copying from Maven Repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.9.9.1).

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.9.1</version>
<!--      <scope>runtime</scope>-->
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.9.1</version>
<!--      <scope>runtime</scope>-->
    </dependency>
```

I commented `<scope>...</scope>` tag , which was probably only for `runtime` thats why ide cant find its repos .
After removing this It starts working  or we can add `compile`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. IDE was not able to find Aspect annotation but after commenting out the <scope>runtine</scope>,  it's working fine.